# find position of html element relative to visible browser area

Tags: jquery, html, position

I have a very long web page, so user needs to scroll to see the whole thing.

Half way down the page, I have an image element `<img>` .  When this element is in the viewable area of the browser, I want to be able to determine the distance between the top of the element and the bottom of the search bar in my browser.

I have jquery installed, so I can leverage it's capabilities.

Is there an easy way to achieve what I'm looking for?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need [**.offset()**](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) and [**.scrollTop()**](http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/) then subtract.